# java8 stream - filter map and aggregate

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Lets say I have a list of rooms

```
List<Room> rooms;
```

And each room has a list of persons.

**Using java8 streams** I want to iterate the list of rooms, get all persons,  execute some method on each node (doSomething()) and get a list of all the filtered objects.

Is this the best practive using java 8?

```
List<Asset> pesonsList= new ArrayList<>();
for (Room room : rooms) 
     room.getPersonsList().stream()
                       .filter(person -> person.isTall())
                       .forEach(person -> {
                               doSomething(person);
                               pesonsList.add(person);
                       });
```

Comment: What is animal? What is animalsList? What does `doSomething()` does?

Comment: If you turn the stream in parallel, the `forEach` could add elements to the list so if it's not synchronized properly you might have issues. You should avoid this kind of programming style (i.e `forEach(p -> someList.add(p))` and use the collector feature instead).

What you can do is use `peek` to execute `doSomething`, on each person instance, then collect the resulting instances into a list.

`List<Person> animalsList = rooms.stream().flatMap(r -> r.getPersonsList().stream()).filter(...).peek(p -> doSomething(p)).collect(...));`

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, how do I turn the foreach to parallel

Comment: `getPersonsList().parallelStream()` or `stream().parallel()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd probably better do it like this:

```
List<Person> persons = 
    rooms.stream()
         .flatMap(room -> room.getPersonsList().stream())
         .filter(Person::isTall)
         .peek(this::doSomething)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Warning "peek" may have concurrency implications. if "doSomething" isn't thread safe, you're in danger of causing unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the @JBNizet answer I'd suggest to replace `getPersonsList()` in `Room` class with `persons()` method: instead of

```
List<Person> getPersonsList() {...}
```

Create this method:

```
Stream<Person> persons() {...}
```

The first advantage is that streaming operations will become shorter:

```
List<Person> persons = rooms.stream()
     .flatMap(Room::persons)
     .filter(Person::isTall)
     .peek(this::doSomething)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The second advantage is that it might be more implementation independent, thus more efficient. Suppose that internally you store persons in the `Set` or in array. When having `getPersonsList()` method you will need to copy all the persons to the new list first. When having `persons()` method, you can easily create a stream directly from your internal data structure whatever it is. I believe, it's Java 8 way to return the stream of internal objects instead of some specific data structure were it `List` or array or whatever.